# Chain jQuery AJAX promises with custom ones

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

I have a particular website where I cannot rely on HTTP status codes, as I normally do, to trigger a success or failure after an AJAX call.
A workaround I've come into, is to build the response as a JSON object that has a "type" property that is valued to "success" or "error".

I've a helper function:

```
function myAjaxCall(data) {
   return $.ajax({method: 'post', url: myUrl, data: data});
}
```

What I want to accomplish is to make this possible:

```
myAjaxCall(data).then(successFunction, failFunction);
```

I've tried to interpose this function:

```
function myPromise(response) {
     var d = $.Deferred();
     response.type == 'success' ? d.resolve() : d.reject();
     return d;
}
```

But I just can't imagine a clean way to insert my promise in the code.

Comment: what is in**responseText** object having while function returns?

Comment: @Akhil The code here is really messed up, but this exposes another problem: how can I pass the AJAX response to my promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chain it with `then`:

```
function myAjaxCall(data) {
    return $.ajax({method: 'post', url: myUrl, data: data}).then(myPromise);
}
```

Your `myPromise` function will receive the response as its argument, and the `then` does return a promise for the result of the call (the promise you return). Btw, you probably should pass some parts of the response to `resolve`/`reject`, so that that your `successFunction` and `failFunction` can access it. Not sure how your responses exactly look like, but as an example:

```
function myPromise(response) {
     var d = $.Deferred();
     response.type == 'success' ? d.resolve(response.data) : d.reject(response.error);
     return d;
}
```

Comment: But how do I pass the response to myPromise?

Comment: @Cranio: You don't. `then` does for you, when the `$.ajax` promise fulfills.

Comment: At last I sorted it out by my myself in the same way, but I think you deserve upvote and answer anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`var myAjaxCall=function(data) { return $.ajax({method: 'post', url: "myUrl", data: data}); } console.log(myAjaxCall("data").responseText()); });` please check the response text your getting after the request. Then pass it on to any variable or function you want.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. How can I get a responseText if the request is asynchronous? You should use a callback. I think you missed the point, and missed also the whole concept of chained asynchronous calls.